# Check if Form method is post or patch in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an edit view and i am using a partial _form view.

Is there a way to check if the form is a patch or post?

What i plan to do is to change the hidden field in edit form

```
@if (form is post)
    {!! Form::hidden('signature') !!}
@else
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('signature', 'Signature: ', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::text('signature', null, ['class' => 'col-md-2 form-control', 'required']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

@endif
```

because this variable is already saved to DB and i want to load it for edit.

Or to check if form is post, that would work also!

Comment: If you are consistent with naming your models when you assign them to the view, you could just simply check `$model->exists` to define if you're doing a post or put.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually pass the variable to a view where I set action, like:

```
$action = 'store';
```

Then I use this variable to build route name:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'post'.$action, ....
```

And detect what type of action is needed:

```
@if ($action == 'store')
```

I guess it's the most readable and simple way to achieve what you're trying to achieve. You can do something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$isPut= Request::isMethod('put');

if($isPut) {
  //
}
```

Comment: The request will mostly be GET I assume (since he's rendering the form). Which doesn't mean the form will be posting to the same method. This is not a solution.